# httpd.exe - Application error while starting apache in xampp server in window 8.1

Tags: xampp, windows-8.1, application-error, system-error

I got

> httpd.exe - system error, The program can't start because
>   api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing while starting Apache
>   server.

I'm using windows 8.1 machine.

To solve that problem i copy .dll files in window32 directory and when i restart the xampp, got new error.

> httpd.exe - Application error The application was unable to start
>   correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close application

Port 80 is not actually being used. I have already reinstalled it many times but same error occurs.

I'm trying to install latest xampp version (7.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

The `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` is part of the Visual C++ 2015 Redistrutable package.

You copied a wrong DLL (wrong CPU archtecture), which generates the error

> 0xc000007b - STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT -  {Bad Image}  %hs is either
>   not designed to run on Windows or it contains  an error. Try
>   installing the program again using the  original installation media or
>   contact your system  administrator or the software vendor for support.

Delete the wrong DLL again, download and install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587).

Answer (score -1):

Run the program with compatibility for Windows Vista service pack 2

Comment: Robert, can you give a little more detail with your answer on how to do this?